# Simulating 'n' step 'm' paths simulation of data using VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, montecarlo

I have decent knowledge of Python and know how to simulate 'n' step , 'm' path data using Python.
Please see the following code

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

#Define Variables
S = 100 #starting data
T = 252 #Number of trading days
mu = 0.2309 #Return
vol = 0.4259 #Volatility
m=1000
#choose number of runs to simulate - I have chosen 1000
for i in range(m):
    #create list of daily returns using random normal distribution
    daily_returns=np.random.normal(mu/T,vol/math.sqrt(T),T)+1

    #set starting price and create price series generated by above random daily returns
    price_list = [S]

    for x in daily_returns:
        price_list.append(price_list[-1]*x)

    #plot data from each individual run which we will plot at the end
    plt.plot(price_list)

#show the plot of multiple price series created above
plt.show()
```

I want to do this in VBA and do not know how to accomplish. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried:Data->Data Analysis-> Random Number generation-> your input

Comment: Yes. But I would like to automate this. Let's day cell A1 and B1 have inputs for n and m respectively and the data is generated accordingly.

Comment: What aspect do you want to automate? You can use `=rand()` which will update each time a cell is edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Norm_Dist for Normal Distribution in VBA which will perform as np.random.normal.

```
Dim dblNorm_Dist As Double
dblNorm_Dist = WorksheetFunction.Norm_Dist(Arg1:= ,Arg2:= ,Arg3:= ,Arg4:= )
Arguments:

Arg1: Double
Arg2: Mean - The arithmetic mean of the distribution.
Arg3: Standard_dev - The standard deviation of the distribution.
Arg4: "Cumulative - A logical value that determines the form of the function. If cumulative is TRUE
```

As the above method does't give the option to mention the size so you can call it in loop and then return the array:

```
For i=1 to T 
   RandomArray=WorksheetFunction.Norm_Dist(Arg2:=mu / T, Arg3:=vol / Sqr(T))
Next i
```